# Search bar that shrinks as you make the page smaller ex: (youtube.com)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

With Twitter-Bootstrap 3 Is it possible to add a search bar that has a set width on your navbar then shrinks on the right side as you make the webpage smaller? For example youtube.com does this with their site. If this is possible could you get me started on how this would be done?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the grid system documentation at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Basically you'll do something like

```
<nav class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8">Search bar here</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">Other header stuff</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?:

```
.navbar{

width:100%;
min-width:500px;

}
```